# where to put robots.txt for a CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, robots.txt

Where to place the robots.txt file in codeigniter.

I dont no how to put where folder.

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robots.txt file MUST be placed in the document root of the host. It will not work in other locations.

If your host is example.com, it needs to be accessible at http://example.com/robots.txt.