# Where to place robots.txt file in Codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have gone through many answers regarding my question but my confusion is still there. Where I should I place 'robots.txt' file in my Codeigniter Project. That means, should I place the file inside the 'application' folder or 'view' folder or 'model' folder or somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but it should be available at the root (e.g. `https://example.com/robots.txt`)

Comment: I faced the same answer many where. But my question is still there.

Answer (score 0):

The robots.txt file MUST be placed in the document root of the host. It will not work in other locations.

If your host is example.com, it needs to be accessible at http://example.com/robots.txt.

Please refer [where to put robots.txt for a CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970833/where-to-put-robots-txt-for-a-codeigniter)

Comment: If I place the file in the root directory then how will I disallow the controller files, view files, model files etc.

Comment: You need to disallow all files using * like "Disallow: /"